# How can I include files into my jar file?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm trying to include some .txt, .png and other files into my jar file. I created a folder under my src folder called "resources". When running the program from my IDE the program can find all files properly. But as soon as I create a jar file out of my code none of the files is found. Of course I used getClass().getResource(...).

Can anyone help me ? :/

Answer (score 1):

In your `pom.xml`, under `<project><build>`, you must include the following:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

(This is assuming that your sources are under `src`, in other words, under `<project><build>` you have this: `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Place all of your resources in the "src" folder (yes, the folder where Java sources are placed)
2. You can load your resource your resources URL:

Here's the code:

```
URL res = AnyClassYouLike.class.getResource("res/icon.png");
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(res);
// I used image just for example! URL objects obtained
// from "getResource" method can be used in a lot of APIs, such as Swing.
```

Or, more generally, as an InputStream object:

```
InputStream is = AnyClassYouLike.class.getResourceAsStream("res/my_resource.ext");
// This will give you the stream to your file. It can be used in some APIs, like an Audio API, very likely.
```

Comment: OT: Who is the user who downvoted a working answer? People on this site are really incoherent!